# React modern calendar datepicker,A change in one input causes a change in all inputs

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I am using react-modern-calendar-datepicker in a table,there are date-picker in every row.when change one input-date-picker,all off them change,I want to each act independently

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "react-modern-calendar-datepicker/lib/DatePicker.css";
import DatePicker from "react-modern-calendar-datepicker";

const App = () => {
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(null);
  return (
    <DatePicker
      value={selectedDay}
      onChange={setSelectedDay}
      shouldHighlightWeekends
      locale="fa" // add this
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you considered having ID on datepicker? Also everytime you use it in table it should have unique ID in order to work

Comment: Thanks, I already checked but it doesn't work :id={"test1"+idx}                                                                   inputName={"test2"+idx},idx is the key in my project

Comment: Probably you are providing same state to every datepicker element

Comment: No,after the compile, each datepicker has a unique ID, but it doesn't work(in my html sorce)

Comment: id and state are different. I believe you are using same state. Please provide minimal reproduceable code or codesandbox

Comment: Good to know that